# exchange own ERC20 token to another token in smart contract for Game

Tags: game-engine, smartcontracts, erc20, nft

I want to deploy a smart contract (ERC20) for the game,
so the purpose is to keep points.

- when someone enters the game, we will ask for some crypto coin (ex. ETH) and give some of our own points
- while playing the game, the user will earn some points.
- Then that user can get crypto coins (ex. ETH) from that points.

I can write a smart contract to manage points.
But I wonder if I can have a function to exchange our points to existing crypto coins (ex ETH) inside of our smart contract.

Does someone know the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the amount of ETH based on a price, and then use the `transfer()` native function of `address payable` type.

```
mapping (address => uint256) pointBalances;

// 1 point for 100 wei, assuming the points have 0 decimals
uint256 price = 100;

function sellPoints(uint256 _amount) external {
    require(pointBalances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
    pointBalances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    uint256 weiAmount = _amount * price;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(weiAmount);
}
```

Comment: Can't we transfer another token like MIM or ADA?

Comment: @Talent You can. An easy way is to invoke the `.transfer()` function of the token contract (not of the `address payable` type as in the answer), which would send the tokens from your contract address to the specified recipient.